# Vim background colour is different

Tags: vim, chocolatey

I'm using gVim 8.x 64-bit on Window 10 that I installed using [chocolatey vim tux package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vim-tux.install).

Just recently I started getting these highlights when I open files.

[image]

I'm using solarized colorscheme. When I set the colorscheme manually, the highlights disappear.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `colorscheme solarized` in your .vimrc? If that doesn't work then colorscheme may be getting overridden from another file. Also the `background` option can affect the colors.

Comment: I have `colorscheme solarized` in my .vimrc. When I start gvim and check `colorscheme` I get back `solarized`. My background is set to dark. Without me changing any settings, the background is fine in 32-bit gvim but has this issue in 64-bit gvim.

Comment: have you tried a minimalist .vimrc that does pretty much nothing except the 3 lines needed for solarized?

syntax enable . 
set background=dark . 
colorscheme solarized .

Comment: @StunBrick It looks like one of the plugins is the culprit. The weird thing is it only happens in 64-bit and not 32-bit. Do you know what property I should be looking at?

Comment: try putting the lines relating to solarized and such at the bottom of the .vimrc. my reasoning being that you say that if you manually set the colorscheme then it works again, so I suspect that your plugin is setting colorschemes, background colors or syntax highlighting. Which plugin was causing the problem?

Comment: That's the thing. I'm setting the colorscheme at the end of the vimrc after loading all the plugins. When I source the vimrc explicitly, the problem goes away.